# A sobrescrita de perguntas é bem aceita na comunidade?

Tags: debate

Imaginem que um usuário fez uma pergunta, mas ela por um motivo qualquer foi colocada como pendente ou fechada, dito isto o autor tenta melhora-la de várias formas mas sem sucesso.

Então ao ver que suas tentativas foram em vão, ele simplesmente sobrescreve a pergunta feita anteriormente com uma outra, totalmente diferente, com o objetivo de usufruir do escopo dela em uma tentativa de retirá-la do estado de pendente ou fechada.

## Dúvida

A sobrescrita de perguntas é considerado uma boa conduta? ou isso piora a situação da reputação do usuário?.

Comment: Lembrando que você pode, também, tirar dúvidas no [chat Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Comment: Depende, o que você tem que evitar de fazer é transformar uma pergunta confusa em outra mais confusa ainda. Mas lembre-se que a pergunta não precisa ser muita ampla e o escopo do problema tem que estar bem definido nela, se você alcançar isso, já é o suficiente para ser uma boa pergunta, compreensível e respondível.

Comment: Isso é um exercício mental? Se não for, o exemplo concreto pode tornar mais fácil dar uma ideia. Agora, o exemplo concreto pode não ser o que se deseja saber, pois pode prender a algo do concreto e impedir a percepção da generalização.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Imaginem que um usuário fez uma pergunta, mas ela por um motivo qualquer foi colocada como pendente ou fechada.

Isso significa que não é uma pergunta adequada.

> Dito isto o autor tenta melhora-la de várias formas mas sem sucesso. Então ao ver que suas tentativas foram em vão, ele simplesmente sobrescreve a pergunta feita anteriormente com uma outra

A "nova" pergunta já surge com um karma ruim, pois terá todo o histórico de edições e votos negativos que a pergunta original. Ela também pode estar sob o sério risco de ser removida do site automaticamente.

> totalmente diferente

Isso é abuso e pode acabar provocando discussão e o efeito meta.

> com o objetivo de usufruir do escopo dela em uma tentativa de retirá-la do estado de pendente ou fechada.

Se a pergunta é totalmente diferente, não deve ter o mesmo escopo, certo? E se o motivo de fechamento for porque a pergunta original estava fora de escopo, isso é bater em um cavalo morto.

> A sobrescrita de perguntas é considerado uma boa conduta?

Não.

> ou isso piora a situação da reputação do usuário?.

Esse comportamento tende a ser recompensado com votos negativos, votos de fechamento e votos de remoção.

Comment: A palavra "escopo" é no sentido de forma, no caso usar a mesma "forma" ou "recipiente" , a sua resposta ficou bem detalhada, agradeço. =)

Answer (score 4):

Não é questão de boa conduta ou do que é bem aceito (bem visto) pela comunidade, ao meu ver, é questão de tornar suas perguntas úteis a comunidade.

Supondo que a primeira não tenha sido respondida (antes de ter sido **fechada**), então pode simplesmente deletar a mais antiga e postar novamente ou pode edita-la (até mesmo completamente), claro que se estiver pendente ou fechada terá que passar pelo processo de reabertura, ainda sim você pode adiantar isto solicitando algum apoio publicando no chat, não quer dizer que vai ser votada para reabrir, vai depender se a pergunta se tornou clara (depende do motivo do fechamento).

Já fiz isto, de postar novamente e deletar a antiga que estava de difícil recuperação. Agora se a pergunta já tem resposta **"satisfatória"** ao autor da pergunta, mesmo que esteja pendente/fechada e/ou negativa, não existe motivos para se criar uma nova.

Vale lembrar que o próprio sistema remove perguntas consideradas abandonadas, ou seja se algo não é útil para o site (e escopo) nem tem motivos para permanecer, se puder refazer na mesma, refaça, se não, delete e comece novamente.

Todavia já sabe que se ficar nessa de Cria e Deleta, uma hora você será vetado do sistema com certeza, o ideal é pensar bem em como criar a pergunta, se é um erro no script **use sempre o MCVE**.

---

### Geral

Jonathas, cá entre nós, como eu comentei na sua outra pergunta, o intuito é ser construtivo, se você realmente esta preocupado com estes tipos de problema, tipo a necessidade de deletar algo é por um destes motivos:

- Você não entendeu que o propósito de criar uma pergunta é torna-la útil para mais pessoas, além de você mesmo
- Você não consegue se comunicar bem via texto

Não é uma critica, é só uma analise sobre o que você deve estar passando, você esta querendo contornar um problema imaginando que a solução é uma coisa, sendo que o problema deve ser resolvido de uma maneira totalmente diferente. O objetivo do site é tirar duvidas sim, mas também é tornar a sua duvida relevante e útil a outros, se você enxerga a necessidade *exagerada* de remover coisas é porque isso esta se repetindo muitas vezes e claramente é um problema contigo e não com a ferramenta.

Um conselho, reveja isso tudo, talvez o seu problema seja "como perguntar", veja como outros perguntam, leia perguntas e respostas no site, não tente resolver esse problema geral com algo que não é a solução.

> **Nota:** Se o seu problema esta sendo em um outro site da rede (stack exchange) que use outro idioma, talvez seja o uso do idioma que você não domina, então voltamos ao problema `Você não consegue se comunicar bem via texto`, neste caso não vejo muito o que fazer, além de tentar melhorar o domínio sobre este outro idioma.

Comment: O problema é que o recurso de deletar a pergunta deve ser usado em ultima instância já que a plataforma puni os usuários que possuem esse tipo de comportamento

Comment: @JonathasB.C. editei a resposta, pessoalmente como eu já comentei na outra resposta, penso que você esta tentando procurar a solução para essa sua dificuldade em usar o site no lugar "errado", o problema esta aonde você não esta enxergando, ou seja não é a ferramenta e suas regras, mas sim o objetivo da ferramenta que você ainda não conseguiu entender bem. Espero realmente que se encontre.

Comment: O problema todo gira em torno do fato de que os usuários não podem errar pois serão seriamente punidos, o problema é que nós aprendemos com o erro, e nesse caso é mais difícil porque precisamos aprender com o erro e acertos dos outros =(

Comment: Estou tentando me adaptar, faz parte do processo, agradeço por ajudar =)

Comment: @JonathasB.C. não é punição, é veto, ser vetado é para evitar problemas pra ti mesmo e para a comunidade e serve no minimo como "parametrizador" para saber que você tem que melhorar e provavelmente aonde tem que melhorar. Não vejo problema algum com o "vetar", basta saber/entender que isso é sinal que você ainda pode melhorar.

Comment: Para clarificar: no segundo parágrafo não estás a dizer que alterar a pergunta completamente não é um problema, certo? Parece-me que o que o ulizador está a perguntar é se, por exemplo: "a minha pergunta sobre um problema qualquer que tenho em javascript for mal recebida, mas eu tenho uma outra pergunta sobre um problema qualquer em PHP — posso só editar a mal recebida completamente mesmo, em vez de fazer uma pergunta nova?" E, para deixar claro, **este cenário é um problema.** Editar o corpo da pergunta por completo, _se for para clarificar o problema original_, é outra conversa...

Comment: @JNat perfeito, vou revisar o texto, as vezes me perco nas palavras.